# How to list Socket.io rooms by names or with certain port

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible to list room  by a name that user gives or a certain port is it possible to search for rooms in socket.io and make the user able to name the room and set number of users to join.
or socket.io can't do these things if so what alternative can do these tasks i'm stuck with those questions for a long time and came hoping for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what you're trying is possible. The first part about naming rooms is possible directly using the API. You can search the `io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms` object for the same.

To make the user be able to give names to the room, join that user's connection to a new room:

```
socket.join(roomName);
```

You can checkout [this blog post](https://ayushgp.github.io/Tic-Tac-Toe-Socket-IO/) for more info on how to restrict people in a room.

This is also a useful resource for namespaces and rooms in Socket.IO: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_rooms.htm